# Remove one of the two "Apply to selected items" submit buttons with Node Bulk Operations

Tags: views

If you make a view and add the **Node operations bulk form**, two "Apply to selected items" boxes are automatically generated like this:

[image: two apply to selected items boxes]

How do I get rid of one of these?

I turned on twig debugging, but the template that is outputting the button is `core/modules/system/templates/container.html.twig`, which is not something that I can easily customize to remove one of the buttons.

How I created the view:

1. Create a new view of *content* showing *fields*.
2. Add *Node operations bulk form* under **Fields**.
3. Save the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [intentional functionality](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_bulk_operations/-/blob/8.x-3.8/src/Plugin/views/field/ViewsBulkOperationsBulkForm.php#L753) for some workflows (for long lists of results).

If you wanted to get rid of the button, you could `hook_form_alter` it away. Form IDs and array structure are dynamic based on your view so you'll have to adjust accordingly based on the view & action button to remove (this can be found in the Views UI, if not known).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  // @TODO: Determine view_id / display_id / field_id for a specific VBO form:
  if ($form_id == 'views_form_' . $view_id . '_' . $display_id) {
    // HEADER ACTION BUTTON:
    //unset($form['header'][$field_id]['actions']);
    // FOOTER ACTION BUTTON:
    //unset($form['actions']['submit']);
  }
```

Comment: For the node operatiosn bulk form, the *$field_id* is `node_bulk_form`.